# PHP Redirect Depending on users Column data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, session, redirect, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a login page with Facebook login API. And i have stored the users data (name, gender and etc) into MySQL database (except the column "gorg" in my table) when they are login.

Then, I'll redirect the users to "newgg.php" which is have two links "Giver" and 
"Gatherer". So, users can choose either one of them.

My sample code:

```
<?php

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include('src/sql_handler.php');
include('src/facebook_handler_core.php');

$new_fb = new facebook_handler_core;
$new_fb->run();

if (isset($_SESSION['gorg']) == "Gatherer") {
  header('Location: map.php');
}

?>
```

My goal is to redirect them depending on the button they push for there FIRST time visiting the page, heres the button code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
      <input type="submit" class="button orange" name="Giver" value="Giver">
</form>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
      <input type="submit" class="button orange" name="Gatherer" value="Gatherer">
</form>
```

and now last but not least, IF they have already previously chosen their type of user it needs to just redirect them depending on what the 'gorg' column reads in the users table.

any ideas to why my codes not working properly?

just in case you need them, here are the sql_handlers

```
<?php

class MySQL_Con {
private $host = 'localhost',
        $user = 'NUNURBSINESS',
        $pass = 'ASKMEANDMAYBE',
        $db = 'teknolog_fruitforest',
        $_CON;

function MySQL_Con() {

    $this->_CON = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
    if(!$this->_CON)
        die(mysql_error());
    else {
        $select_db = mysql_select_db($this->db);

        if(!$select_db)
            die('Error Connecting To Database'.mysql_error());
    }
}

function End_Con() {
    mysql_close($this->_CON);
}
}
?>
```

and now the facebook_handler_core.php

```
<?php

class facebook_handler_core extends MySQL_Con {
public $session,$_INFO = array(),$U_INFO = array();

public function run() {
    require('src/facebook.php');

    $set_fb = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => 'MYAPPID',
                'secret' => 'CANTTELLYOU',
                'cookie' => true));

    $this->session = $set_fb->getUser();

    if($this->session != 0) {
        $this->_INFO = $set_fb->api('/me');

        if(!empty($this->_INFO))
            $this->fb_session_handler();
    }
}

function fb_session_handler() {
    $SQL_CON = new MySQL_Con;
    $SQL_CON->MySQL_Con();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND email = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($this->_INFO['email'])."'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $this->U_INFO = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
    } else {
        $photolink = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->session.'/picture?type=square';

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(oauth_uid, oauth_provider, username, first_name, last_name, email, pic_square, gorg, gender)VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($this->session)."','facebook',    '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->_INFO['name'])."',      '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->_INFO['first_name'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($this->_INFO['last_name'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($this->_INFO['email'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($photolink)."','null','".mysql_real_escape_string($this->_INFO['gender'])."')") or die(mysql_error());

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($this->_INFO['email'])."'") or die(mysql_error());

        $this->U_INFO = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());

    }

    $SQL_CON->End_Con();
    $gorg = $this->U_INFO['gorg'];

    if($gorg != null) {
        $_SESSION['gorg'] = $gorg;
    }

    $_SESSION['email'] = $this->U_INFO['email'];
    $_SESSION['image'] = $this->U_INFO['pic_square'];
    $_SESSION['gender'] = $this->U_INFO['gender'];

    if($gorg != null) {
        if($gorg == 'Giver') {
            //redirect to Giver
            header('Location: picktreetype.php');
        }

        if($gorg == "Gatherer") {
            //redirect to Gatherer
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function update_user($param) {
    $SQL_CON = new MySQL_Con;
    $SQL_CON->MySQL_Con();

    if($param == 'Giver')
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET gorg='".mysql_real_escape_string($param)."', FF_Points='100' WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email'])."'") or die(mysql_error());

    if($param == 'Gatherer')
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET gorg='".mysql_real_escape_string($param)."', FF_Points='30' WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email'])."'") or die(mysql_error());

    $SQL_CON->End_Con();

    if(!$query)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance, i just cant get enough out of this site when it comes to gaining help and proper guidance i really appreciate all the help anyone has ever given me in the past.

Comment: Did you want to store the gorg in the database or a session?

Comment: You should also create variables for things in a query like $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($this->_INFO['last_name'])

Comment: i already am storing it correctly, it gets added to the DB no problem, im looking to redirect the page to a new specific page, for example Gatherer get redirected to gatherermap.php and giver gets redirected to picktreetype.php thats all im having troubles with

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're doing

```
isset($_SESSION['gorg']) == "Gatherer"
```

as `isset()` returns a boolean result which, using `==`, will match any non-explicitly-false value. You would have had direct evidence of the problem if you would have used `===` (identity comparison operator).

So, in your case, "Gatherer" is evaluated as non-FALSE, aka TRUE.

Every time.

You shouldn't use this kind of comparison; instead try:

```
isset($_SESSION['gorg']) && $_SESSION['gorg'] == "Gatherer"
```

if you wish to keep checking whether `gorg` is set before doing any other evaluation.

Comment: This solution didnt seem to work... i only changed it in the header on the newgg.php though, is there other places i should make these changes?

Comment: I noticed you used this comparison in your sample code at the beginning of your post. Perhaps I'm not completely understanding your POV, btw I see you use header('Location: map.php'), whilst you're telling about redirecting to newgg.php. Maybe I'm a little bit confused about it ;) Anyways I was referring to the comparison into your sample code above, first box in your OP.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on to what page its redirecting to. A Giver goes to picktreetype.php and a gatherer goes to gatherermap.php

Comment: So how about instead of using my session, i just pull directly from the database, i could care less if it pulls from the session, to me pulling from the database would seem to be more accurate and fail proof anyways so can you show me some example coding of how to achieve redirecting a user according to there user type? Instead of this whole sessions stuff.

Comment: @AaronRussell No, it's all right to pick up user type from session, as well as from the database. Combining the two it's maybe the most direct way to let authentication's user type persist between pages. Generally speaking your technique is correct (and I would use it too), maybe just a little adjustment: users authenticate, you store in $_SESSION user's attributes that have to persist between pages (typically user id), then - when your site needs it - contextually determine what to do with your user by fetching relevant user's profile data from database with $_SESSION['uid'] as key.